# Send out value of drop down box with two different buttons with HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a drop down menu and have two buttons on a page, where one button will send out something like:

```
url/?tile=x&status=on
```

if the "On" button is pressed

or

```
url/?tile=x&status=off
```

if the off button is pressed

x = is the value in the drop down menu

I can do something like this:

```
<form>
Select Tile For On/Off
<select id="tileSelect2" data-range="63" name="tile"></select>
<script>
  var select = document.getElementById("tileSelect2");
  var range = select.dataset.range;
  for (var i=0; i<+range; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("option");                
    node.value = i;
    node.text  = i;
    select.appendChild(node);
  }
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Switch Tile On">
<input type="submit" value="Switch Tile Off">

</form>
```

But that will just send the same thing out for both buttons. Is there a way of making different buttons do different things? I'd be happy if it sent:

```
url/?tileon=x
```

and

```
url/?tileoff=x
```

Or the other option suggested above.

I've found various methods where you can run a script from a button press, but I can't work out from that how to make it send out the value selected to the server.

I need to keep it simple as it's being hardcoded into an embedded sever.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your submit buttons names, it will create an extra space in the url if the method is set on `GET`(which you probably use):

```
<input type="submit" name="on" value="Switch Tile On">
<input type="submit" name="off" value="Switch Tile Off">
```

You will get

```
url/tile=x&on=Switch+Tile+On
```

If you hit the first button. Now you can check whether the button was "on" or "off" with

```
if(isset($_GET['on']))
```

or

```
if(isset($_GET['off']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `<hidden/>` element to your form declaration, then you supply a value to your `<hidden/>` before the form is posted in order to pass along the value to the form on the server.

```
<form>

Select Tile For On/Off
<select id="tileSelect2" data-range="63" name="tile"></select>
<script>
  var select = document.getElementById("tileSelect2");
  var range = select.dataset.range;
  for (var i=0; i<+range; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("option");                
    node.value = i;
    node.text  = i;
    select.appendChild(node);
  }
</script>

<hidden id="switchValue" name="switchValue" value="" />

<script>
function switch(val) {
    document.getElementById("switchValue").value = val;
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Switch Tile On" onclick="switch('on')">
<input type="submit" value="Switch Tile Off" onclick="switch('off')">

</form>
```

Comment: I had a go with this but it just sends out:

url/?tile=11

Comment: it doesn't seem like your hidden value is getting set.  'stupid question' - have you debugged to make sure the hidden value is being set?